# java.lang.AssertionError when running mvn package

Tags: java, maven

I am running this:

```
mvn -e package exec:java -DskipTests
```

I have this error trace in the console:

```
[INFO] Compiling 5 source files to /home/oleg/codes/oresoftware/vertx.api/target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.366 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-01-27T16:10:28-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/70M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------
constituent[0]: file:/usr/share/maven/conf/logging/
constituent[1]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-resolver-transport-wagon.jar
constituent[2]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-builder-support-3.x.jar
constituent[3]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/sisu-inject.jar
constituent[4]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-embedder-3.x.jar
constituent[5]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/wagon-http-shaded.jar
constituent[6]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-resolver-connector-basic.jar
constituent[7]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-resolver-api.jar
constituent[8]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/plexus-utils.jar
constituent[9]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/commons-cli.jar
constituent[10]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-resolver-util.jar
constituent[11]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-settings-builder-3.x.jar
constituent[12]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.x.jar
constituent[13]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/sisu-plexus.jar
constituent[14]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/commons-lang3.jar
constituent[15]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/javax.inject.jar
constituent[16]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar
constituent[17]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-model-3.x.jar
constituent[18]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/plexus-interpolation.jar
constituent[19]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-resolver-provider-3.x.jar
constituent[20]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/plexus-component-annotations.jar
constituent[21]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/slf4j-api.jar
constituent[22]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-core-3.x.jar
constituent[23]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/jsr250-api.jar
constituent[24]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/cdi-api.jar
constituent[25]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/jansi.jar
constituent[26]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/plexus-sec-dispatcher.jar
constituent[27]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-artifact-3.x.jar
constituent[28]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/plexus-cipher.jar
constituent[29]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-plugin-api-3.x.jar
constituent[30]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/wagon-provider-api.jar
constituent[31]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-model-builder-3.x.jar
constituent[32]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/jcl-over-slf4j.jar
constituent[33]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-resolver-spi.jar
constituent[34]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-compat-3.x.jar
constituent[35]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/wagon-file.jar
constituent[36]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-resolver-impl.jar
constituent[37]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/aopalliance.jar
constituent[38]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-settings-3.x.jar
constituent[39]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guava.jar
constituent[40]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/commons-io.jar
constituent[41]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-slf4j-provider-3.x.jar
constituent[42]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-shared-utils.jar
---------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.error(Assert.java:155)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.check(Assert.java:46)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Modules.enter(Modules.java:244)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.readSourceFile(JavaCompiler.java:829)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$ImplicitCompleter.complete(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1506)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:633)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.complete(Symbol.java:1308)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.complete(Type.java:1139)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.getTypeArguments(Type.java:1065)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Printer.visitClassType(Printer.java:237)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Printer.visitClassType(Printer.java:52)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.accept(Type.java:992)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Printer.visit(Printer.java:136)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.formatArgument(AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.java:197)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.formatArguments(AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.java:165)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.BasicDiagnosticFormatter.formatMessage(BasicDiagnosticFormatter.java:111)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.BasicDiagnosticFormatter.formatMessage(BasicDiagnosticFormatter.java:67)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.formatArgument(AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.java:183)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.formatArguments(AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.java:165)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.BasicDiagnosticFormatter.formatMessage(BasicDiagnosticFormatter.java:111)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.BasicDiagnosticFormatter.formatMessage(BasicDiagnosticFormatter.java:67)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.JCDiagnostic.getMessage(JCDiagnostic.java:771)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.ClientCodeWrapper$DiagnosticSourceUnwrapper.getMessage(ClientCodeWrapper.java:799)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:131)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile(JavacCompiler.java:174)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:952)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:158)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:955)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:290)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:194)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>huru</groupId>
  <artifactId>vertx-start-project</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <vertx.version>3.6.0</vertx.version>
    <!--<main.class>huru.Start</main.class>-->
    <main.verticle>huru.MainVerticle</main.verticle>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.21</slf4j.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
        <artifactId>vertx-stack-depchain</artifactId>
        <version>${vertx.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-mysql-postgresql-client</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-web</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-jdbc-client</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.github.jklingsporn</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-jooq-classic-reactive</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-unit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
          <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.6.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.5.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>12</source>
            <target>9</target>
            <useIncrementalCompilation>true</useIncrementalCompilation>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <manifestEntries>
                    <Main-Class>io.vertx.core.Launcher</Main-Class>
                    <Main-Verticle>${main.verticle}</Main-Verticle>
                  </manifestEntries>
                </transformer>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                  <resource>META-INF/services/io.vertx.core.spi.VerticleFactory</resource>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
              <artifactSet>
              </artifactSet>
              <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-fat.jar</outputFile>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>io.vertx.core.Launcher</mainClass>
          <!--<mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>-->
          <arguments>
            <argument>run</argument>
            <argument>${main.verticle}</argument>
            <!--<argument>${main.class}</argument>-->
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>10</source>
          <target>10</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

anyone know what that error is about?

Comment: What happens if you run `mvn package -DskipTests` followed by `mvn exec:java`? In my experience you cannot mix lifecycle executions and plugin goals in the same mvn invocation.

Comment: You can see same issue has been already resolve
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46878649/maven-compilation-issue-with-java-9