# Mvn compile issue

Tags: maven

I am facing this issue while compiling the code.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError
jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$ImplicitCompleter.complete(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1521)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven compilation issue with Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46878649/maven-compilation-issue-with-java-9)

Comment: Are you using the most recent version of the maven-compiler-plugin?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like [MCOMPILER-346](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-346) ("JDK10: Compiler plugin trips AssertionError inside javac when using javax.tools API"):

> Compilation fails with a crash  inside javac unless the maven-compiler-plugin is configured with
>
> `<forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>`

As of June 2020, the bug's not fixed. Try the workaround suggested.