# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-3

After code refactoring I'm getting this error whe nI try to compile Maven project:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14\bin\java.exe" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\plte1219\Desktop\CJM\media_auth -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven-event-listener.jar" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=59675:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds.license" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version2020.1.2 clean package
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------------< org.engine:engine_auth >-----------------------
[INFO] Building engine_auth 1.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ engine_auth ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\plte1219\Desktop\CJM\media_auth\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ engine_auth ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] Copying 6 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ engine_auth ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 38 source files to C:\Users\plte1219\Desktop\CJM\media_auth\target\classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  11.174 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-25T22:47:39+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------
constituent[0]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/conf/logging/
constituent[1]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/cdi-api-1.0.jar
constituent[2]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/commons-cli-1.4.jar
constituent[3]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/commons-io-2.5.jar
constituent[4]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar
constituent[5]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/guava-25.1-android.jar
constituent[6]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/guice-4.2.1-no_aop.jar
constituent[7]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/jansi-1.17.1.jar
constituent[8]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/javax.inject-1.jar
constituent[9]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.29.jar
constituent[10]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/jsoup-1.12.1.jar
constituent[11]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/jsr250-api-1.0.jar
constituent[12]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-artifact-3.6.3.jar
constituent[13]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-builder-support-3.6.3.jar
constituent[14]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-compat-3.6.3.jar
constituent[15]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-core-3.6.3.jar
constituent[16]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-embedder-3.6.3.jar
constituent[17]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-model-3.6.3.jar
constituent[18]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-model-builder-3.6.3.jar
constituent[19]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-plugin-api-3.6.3.jar
constituent[20]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.6.3.jar
constituent[21]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-resolver-api-1.4.1.jar
constituent[22]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-resolver-connector-basic-1.4.1.jar
constituent[23]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-resolver-impl-1.4.1.jar
constituent[24]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-resolver-provider-3.6.3.jar
constituent[25]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-resolver-spi-1.4.1.jar
constituent[26]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-resolver-transport-wagon-1.4.1.jar
constituent[27]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-resolver-util-1.4.1.jar
constituent[28]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-settings-3.6.3.jar
constituent[29]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-settings-builder-3.6.3.jar
constituent[30]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-shared-utils-3.2.1.jar
constituent[31]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-slf4j-provider-3.6.3.jar
constituent[32]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.4.jar
constituent[33]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.3.4.jar
constituent[34]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-cipher-1.7.jar
constituent[35]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-component-annotations-2.1.0.jar
constituent[36]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-interpolation-1.25.jar
constituent[37]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
constituent[38]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-utils-3.2.1.jar
constituent[39]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.29.jar
constituent[40]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/wagon-file-3.3.4.jar
constituent[41]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/wagon-http-3.3.4-shaded.jar
constituent[42]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/wagon-provider-api-3.3.4.jar
---------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.error(Assert.java:155)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.check(Assert.java:46)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Modules.enter(Modules.java:247)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.readSourceFile(JavaCompiler.java:836)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$ImplicitCompleter.complete(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1588)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:670)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.complete(Symbol.java:1383)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.complete(Type.java:1157)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.getTypeArguments(Type.java:1083)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Printer.visitClassType(Printer.java:237)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Printer.visitClassType(Printer.java:52)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.accept(Type.java:1010)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Printer.visit(Printer.java:136)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.formatArgument(AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.java:199)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.formatArguments(AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.java:167)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.BasicDiagnosticFormatter.formatMessage(BasicDiagnosticFormatter.java:111)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.BasicDiagnosticFormatter.formatMessage(BasicDiagnosticFormatter.java:67)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.formatArgument(AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.java:185)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.formatArguments(AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.java:167)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.BasicDiagnosticFormatter.formatMessage(BasicDiagnosticFormatter.java:111)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.BasicDiagnosticFormatter.formatMessage(BasicDiagnosticFormatter.java:67)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.JCDiagnostic.getMessage(JCDiagnostic.java:788)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.ClientCodeWrapper$DiagnosticSourceUnwrapper.getMessage(ClientCodeWrapper.java:835)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:131)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile(JavacCompiler.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1134)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:187)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
```

I tried to delete folder `.m2` but the problem is not fixed. Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Which file is it that crashes the Java compiler? What is the minimum version of that file that still crashes the Java compiler? Without this information, we cannot help you.

Comment: I downgraded to Java 8 and I managed to compile it. After that I switched again to Java 14 and now it's working =)

Answer (score 88):

I had the same issue.
Forcing `maven-compiler-plugin` to use `javac` helped me discover actual compilation errors.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

More details can be found in this [Maven Compiler Plugin bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-346)

Edit: the issue is fixed in `maven-compiler-plugin` version 3.10.1

Comment: How did you find it? Thanks, this fix made my day.

Comment: Thanks!! It worked for me

Comment: Upon doing this, my project that had been building for years reported 28 errors on missing dependencies that are there - after I took out the only file that had changed in weeks.  What compiler is eclipse normally using on a "maven install"?

Comment: @DrDave Eclipse reports the java executable it's using at the very top of the console window.

Comment: This fixed it for me - I had <version>3.8.0</version> and updated it to <version>3.11.0</version> and that resolved that issue

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this very unhelpful error while compiling a project, and discovered that the problem was a reference to a non-existent static inner class inside another class (it had been renamed). Once that was resolved, the error went away.

Solution: look for compilation errors. Sometimes your IDE may be able to find them for you, without raising this error.

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations, you've found a bug in the Java compiler. That's rare. It's a bug in the compiler because the class `com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.error` clearly says it's from `javac`, the Java compiler, and the stack trace provides really good hints on how to reproduce the bug.

Please report the bug to the OpenJDK project. There's the [compiler-dev mailing list](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/compiler-dev) where you can ask first and contact the main developers of the OpenJDK project.

When you report the bug, make sure that you can reliably reproduce the bug and try to reproduce the bug in the simplest way possible by stripping away any unnecessary code. Typically you end up with a project containing at most 5 files. [Here's a guide for reporting good bugs](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/bugs.html).

Comment: He's using command line Java 14 (`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14\bin\java.exe`) and is compiling from Maven, not from IntelliJ IDEA. Maven is not using JetBrains Runtime which you can tell from the command line posted in the question. Why do you think it should be reported to JetBrains?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks for reading my answer carefully. I didn't read the question carefully enough. I fixed my answer.

Comment: It may not be a bug really... I have seen it from like this post before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46878649/maven-compilation-issue-with-java-9. It could be due to conflicts in the cached classes. In which case running the `mvn clean` command first then the appropriate Maven build command would make the issue go away.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party but I guess my answer would help someone in future.

I also faced the same issue but changing the version of local dependencies fixed my issue.

project-a is a dependency in project-b. When I changed the project-a code and didn't update the version in project-b, the issue appeared.

Once I updated the dependency in both the pom.xml files, everything started working.

Above is one of the root cause but you may have a different situation.

Comment: what dependency have you changed specifically? -this answer is not clear

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after refactoring, and in my case, the crash was produced by the import of an unexisting class.
Unfortunately, the compiler and the IDE were unaware of that issue.

If you enable **forceJavacCompilerUse** as @Yaroslav Buhaiev suggests, you will see more meaningful errors.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile 
   (default-compile) on project reporting: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /Users/myuser/projects/myproject//src/main/java/com/example/UserResource.java:[76,111] 
   error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable MY_PARAM
[ERROR]   location: class UserRepository
```

Answer (score 0):

with the below solution I am able to fix the error.

Root Cause - There was an unexisting bean class in the config folder inside a specific module.

Fix - remove that unused bean configuration from the config folder

Example -
I removed some class A from the gateways module but the bean configuration still exists in the config folder. After removing the bean config, the build is success.

Editor - IntelliJ Idea, JDK 11