# maven install - Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins, Fatal error compiling

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-3, maven-plugin

I am getting the below error when i run the "mvn install" command on command line or via intellji task.

**Does Maven Version Causing the issue?**
My pom.xml is referring the maven dependncy as 3.7.0 but my intellij referring to a different version maven from its plugin directory(C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin). I have another version of maven which is installed on (C:\Users<myname>.m2\repository)

Due to this conflict, i am getting the error when running "mvn install" command.

How can i resolve this maven version conflict and instruct intellij to use the maven version from my pom.xml?

```
mvn install -X



 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  52.969 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-09-15T15:36:14-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project myServices: Fatal error compiling: CompilerException: NullPo
interException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project myServices:
Fatal error compiling
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fatal error compiling
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1086)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.CompilerException
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess (JavaxToolsCompiler.java:173)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile (JavacCompiler.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1075)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.readSourceFile (JavaCompiler.java:840)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$ImplicitCompleter.complete (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1588)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete (Symbol.java:670)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.complete (Symbol.java:1383)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.complete (Type.java:1157)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.getTypeArguments (Type.java:1083)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Printer.visitClassType (Printer.java:237)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Printer.visitClassType (Printer.java:52)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.accept (Type.java:1010)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Printer.visit (Printer.java:136)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.formatArgument (AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.java:199)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.formatArguments (AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.java:167)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.BasicDiagnosticFormatter.formatMessage (BasicDiagnosticFormatter.java:111)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.BasicDiagnosticFormatter.formatMessage (BasicDiagnosticFormatter.java:67)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.formatArgument (AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.java:185)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.formatArguments (AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.java:167)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.BasicDiagnosticFormatter.formatMessage (BasicDiagnosticFormatter.java:111)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.BasicDiagnosticFormatter.formatMessage (BasicDiagnosticFormatter.java:67)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.JCDiagnostic.getMessage (JCDiagnostic.java:788)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.ClientCodeWrapper$DiagnosticSourceUnwrapper.getMessage (ClientCodeWrapper.java:835)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess (JavaxToolsCompiler.java:131)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile (JavacCompiler.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1075)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not clear that this is a Maven nor an IntelliJ issue.  What comes after the "fatal error compiling" error?

Comment: Does the build work in the command line using Maven? Does it help if you configure IntelliJ IDEA to use the same Maven version as works in the command line instead of the bundled one?

Comment: Note that maven-compiler-plugin version has nothing to do with the Maven version, these can be completely different.

Comment: @CrazyCoder nope. I am able to build the project successfully using intellij. If i use the command line "mvn install" then i get the fatal error message "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins: maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0: compile(default-compile) on project myAppServices: Fatal error compiling"

Comment: Make sure the same JDK and Maven versions are used in IntelliJ IDEA and in the command line.

Comment: @stdunbar i am getting the error message when i run the command "mvn install" on both  command line or via intellji ("mvn install" task)

Comment: Right - but you're not answering my question.  What comes after the compilation failure message when running `mvn install`?  You're not showing enough information.

Comment: Does it work with JDK 11 instead of JDK 14?

Comment: [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  34.315 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-09-15T14:47:40-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project myServices: Fatal error compiling: CompilerException: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

Comment: Run with verbose debug logging to get more details.

Comment: @CrazyCoder i just updated the detailed error log in my question.

Comment: Does `<forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>` help? See [this Java bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8216202?focusedCommentId=14234854&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-14234854).

Comment: @CrazyCoder beat me to it - see also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46878649/maven-compilation-issue-with-java-9)

Comment: @CrazyCoder i tried to add the property like below but still having the error? Am i adding it in the right place of my pom.xml?

Comment: <plugin><groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId><artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.7.0</version>       <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                    <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

Comment: Yes, should be inside `<configuration>`. If it doesn't help, can you post the new exception? As far as I understand with this option applied you will not have `org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess` in the stacktrace.

Comment: Yes. You are right. That error got fixed. Now i am getting jfreechart runtime exception.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I got the below error now. Do you have any thought?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63922563/mvn-install-build-error-with-org-jfree-chart-with-intellij-version-2020-2