# mvn install - build error with org.jfree.chart with IntelliJ Version 2020.2

Tags: java, maven-3, jfreechart

I am having the mvn install Build Failure issue with jfree.chart jar having issue with latest version of IntelliJ 2020.2. I am using maven 3.6.3.

The same mvn install works fine for my colleague who has 2019 of IntelliJ.

[image]

Comment: Does it work in the command line outside of the IDE?

Comment: Nope. Same error.

Comment: Please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Add `-e` to the `mvn` command. I encountered this [issue](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/issues/114) when building from source tagged 1.5.0.

Comment: I think i had some corrupted repo on my .m2 folder. After i remove the .m2\repositories folder and ran "mvn -U clean install". My issue got resolved. Thanks everyone for offering me the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i had some corrupted repo on my .m2 folder. After i remove the .m2\repositories folder and ran "mvn -U clean install". My issue got resolved. Thanks everyone for offering me the help.